# My computer turns off after 0.5 seconds

Tags: boot, hardware-failure, power

Since this morning, my computer won't start. I was using it normally (playing) and it suddenly turned off. Now it won't start. Sometimes, when I press the power button, it starts for half a second to a second, and then turns back off. I noticed this happens more when I unplug the power chord and plug it back in.

I didn't change anything in the hardware, and I don't think it's a software issue since it doesn't stay on long enough for anything to boot.

I'm thinking it could be related to my power unit but I want to be sure before replacing it.

How do I diagnose and fix the problem?

I plugged my power chord on another computer and it worked (at least it stayed on). I also checked that everything is properly plugged in on the motherboard.

Comment: this set of answers has some good info and possibilities for what the problem might be. http://superuser.com/questions/361464/mainboard-shuts-itself-off-after-half-a-second-or-so?rq=1  At the least you need to put up all your specs for the computers parts.  Disconnect every thing stuffed into ports on the outside, untill you at least get to posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be due to the power supply unit issue or a motherboard issue. Your computer goes to the protected mode due to the overcurrent.
The easiest way to diagnose this - to connect another PSU to the motherboard. I advise to disconnect all peripheral devices file HDD, ODD, etc.

All the rest of the diagnostics required some electronics understanding and measurements of the input voltage on the motherboard.

Comment: Failed power supply seems the most likely.

Comment: It was indeed. I diagnosed it using the paperclip test.